# SEO & Angular Universal (Angular 5)

Tags: seo, google

We are using Angular Universal to render our Angular 5 app. HTML5 is properly rendered by the NodeJS server, but Google does not render the page visually even if it sees the HTML5.

This is how Google sees the page

[image: This is how Google sees the page]

This is the code Google sees

[image: This is the code Google sees]

So, even if it sees the proper code, it does not render it visually correctly.

1. Is this harmful for SEO?
2. Maybe it is caused by a component such as https://material.angular.io/components/tabs/overview, so Google does not render its own library?

Comment: Angular is a very poor framework for SEO.   I wouldn't use it if you need to have your content indexed by search engines.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Angular is destined only for projects where SEO is definitely NOT in the scope of requirements. Any SEO question regarding Angular shows that is actually too late to think about SEO.

To your questions:

1. yes, it is harmful. It shows, that the HTML rendering fails massively.
2. I would say the rendering fail is caused not by component itself, but rather by its implementation. Looking into HTML source code of example under https://material.angular.io/components/tabs/examples i see completely different HTML markup of tabs, as "Fetch as Google" displays.